# How to change label text to a Attribute value

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I was trying to make a TextLabel that if a player is added into the game, then the text of label will change to the attribute value of the player. I tried to make but it didn't work.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
local ItemToSell = Player:GetAttribute("ItemToSell")
local Money = Player:GetAttribute("Money")

script.Parent.ItemToSell.Text = ItemToSell
script.Parent.Money.Text = Money 

end)
```

Comment: I don't see any label in your code

Comment: You probably forgot to change the `Text` property: `script.Parent.ItemToSell.Text = ItemToSell` and `script.Parent.Money.Text = Money`

Comment: i forgor that 

Comment: oh, the label is Renamed to ItemToSell and Money

Comment: same thing, i changed the code putting .Text and didn't work

Comment: Try calling `tostring`: `script.Parent.ItemToSell.Text = tostring(ItemToSell)` and `script.Parent.Money.Text = tostring(Money)`

Comment: i tried now but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work because your code is being run right after a player joins, this means any attributes that are being set will not exist when your code is called.

This may be a good read for you: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Data-store

Comment: i made a code that if a attribute of a player changes will set the text the value of attribute